# How to remove white background from product images in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: product-images, catalog, magento2.2.6

How to remove white background from product images in Magento 2.2.6?
[Please check this screenshort](http://prntscr.com/lh7to4)

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know it's helpful for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **view.xml** set "width" and "height" as you wish and then "transparency" , "aspect_ratio" and "frame" to "false"

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
                <transparency>false</transparency>
                <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Comment: not working please let me know step by step, because i put this code in this path"http://prntscr.com/lh8ax0"

Comment: There are "m2-theme" maybe your theme. So, into m2-theme find etc/view.xml file.

Comment: Pleasure to help you :) You can upvote as well :)

Answer (score 0):

find **category_page_grid** In view.xml of your theme and add

```
<frame>false</frame>
```

node it will remove the white background / frame from images ( this will only remove from listing page )

your code will be li like this:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```