# How to remove white background from product image in Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento2, product-images, slider

i want to remove white background for product image but it's not working all... i have apply [How to remove white background from product images in Magento 2.2.6?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249667/how-to-remove-white-background-from-product-images-in-magento-2-2-6) this solution but still same..

Please check SS for slider https://nimb.ws/RpcNFm

```
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
                <transparency>false</transparency>
                <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
```

Thanks in advance for help !!

Answer (score 0):

It's Maybe Magento Core issue. Not sure, It's solved or not. But, If you didn't get result using XML change then, you can create plugin for that :

> **app/code/RH/Helloworld/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image">
    <plugin name="remove_white_bg_plugin" type="RH\Helloworld\Plugin\Product\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin File :

> **app/code/RH/Helloworld/Plugin/Product/Image.php**

```
<?php

namespace RH\Helloworld\Plugin\Product;

class Image {
    public function beforeSetKeepFrame($image, $keep)
    {
        if (is_string($keep)) {
            $keep = (strtolower($keep) === 'true') ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return [$keep];
    }
}
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: For testing purpose i have added above code to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image file directly but it's not working...... Original image has white background and it's jpg image

any another way for same... thanks @rohan